# HTTP GET server in C, long waiting (TTFB)

Tags: c, http, httpserver, recv

I am trying to build some http server. My procedure is easy: I am getting http request, waiting to its end and send my response after that. 
Unfortunately there is a gap for a couple seconds between receiving a browser header and receiving an empty buffer from *recv* to detect that is the end and now I can send a response.

```
socklen_t clientAddressLength;
int clientSocket = accept(socket, (struct sockaddr *)&socketAddress, &clientAddressLength);
if (clientSocket < 0) {ESP_LOGI(TAG, "failed 3!"); goto network_task_finish;}

if (setsockopt(clientSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
   ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Cannot Set SO_SNDTIMEO for socket");
if (setsockopt(clientSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
   ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Cannot Set SO_RCVTIMEO for socket");
while (1) {
   ret = recv(clientSocket, recv_buf, NETWORK_RECV_BUF_LEN - 1, 0);
   if (ret <= 0) break;
   if (ret <= 2 && *recv_buf == '\r') break;
   if (ret < NETWORK_RECV_BUF_LEN)
      recv_buf[ret] = '\0';
   ESP_LOGI(TAG, "RECV");
   if (strstr(recv_buf," HTTP/")) {
      char *ptr = recv_buf;
      if (strncmp(recv_buf, "GET ", 4) == 0)
         ptr += 4;
      else if (strncmp(recv_buf, "POST ", 4) == 0)
         ptr += 5;
      else
         continue;
      ESP_LOGI(TAG, "HEADER!");
   }
}

ESP_LOGI(TAG, "RESPONSE");
send(clientSocket, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n", 17, 0);
send(clientSocket, "Content-Type: text/html\r\n", 25, 0);
send(clientSocket, "Connection: close\r\n", 19, 0);
send(clientSocket, "\r\n", 2, 0);
send(clientSocket, "WORKS", 5, 0);
ESP_LOGI(TAG, "SEND");
```

log:

```
server: RECV
server: HEADER!
... long time ...
server: RESPONSE
server: SEND
```

What is an accurate way to handle the request?
Maybe I dont have to wait for its end or I can detect the header end other way

Comment: um ... you dont need the socket-timeouts - these are valid for the **transport layer** whereas HTTP operates on **application layer**. If your **socket** times out your remote daemon is faulty .... **very** faulty because TCP offers *KEEPALIVE* packets for that kind of problem, also : automatic segmentation. I think you need to debug your remote server, first

Comment: indeed ... also : read about Ethernet and the OSI model. Do not manipulate network layer options just yet ... that'll get you into trouble. I know : a lof of internet websites claim that its the cool thing to do ... but its really not. As long as you dont develop embedded webservers which operate in private or corporate, isolated networks you will most likely not need them ever.

Comment: On an unrelated note, don't call `send` multiple times. Concatenate all of the response (header and body) into a single buffer, and then call `send` once using that buffer. You only need to split it up into multiple `send` calls if the data to send is larger than the network stacks underlying buffers.

Comment: TCP does that automatically .... there is no need to split anything into pieces - everything above `MTU` will be split up and reassembled, with checksums and all, it just works. That is not the case for UDP, of course but one should'nt use UDP for reliable data transmission anyway - thats the domain of TCP and SCTP. UDP is fine for unimportant notifications or high-frequency, minor game updates from a gameserver but not much else ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem doesn't seem to be that you don't know how the request ends (with a single blank line) but in how you *check* for it.

You have to remember that HTTP is built on top of TCP, and that TCP is a *streaming* protocol without message boundaries or fixed-size packets.

That means you can get the whole request in a single `recv` call, or two, or three or more. And you only detect the end of the header if a single `recv` call gives you *just* the empty line and nothing else, which is a very unlikely event. This might also give you a *false* end-of-request, as the newline might be in the middle of the header.

Instead I recommend you redesign your receiving code to call `recv` in a loop and append to a buffer. Then in the loop check if the last *four* bytes are the double newline sequence (`\r\n\r\n`). If it is, *then* you have found the end of the request and can break the loop and continue with processing the request and actually check what is wanted (`GET` or `POST` etc.).